# How do they shoot accident scenes in movies in public areas?

Tags: production, m.s.-dhoni-untold-story

Recently I watched *M.S. Dhoni: The Untold Story*, there is a scene where Priyanka Jha is killed in a car accident:

[image: car accident as seen in the movie (picture is safe for work)]

Looks like this scene was shot in public areas. **In reality, people panic and may call an ambulance**. How did they shoot this scene without any nuisance?

Comment: Presumably they do a bit of warning ahead? Putting up signs the week prior in the streets where they're going to shoot, etc

Comment: Also, the many crewmembers, cameras, etc all over the street would presumably give the game away.

Comment: It depends, but it’s quite common to actually close off all the streets and everything and everyone you see in the film is an extra, not a member of the public. Also the special effects will be done later so what is actually shot might not be at all concerning to people nearby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do these kinds of scenes, depending on the budget. If there is a lot of money to produce the movie, the studio might build a piece of the street to shoot their movie. In this case, the set is a closed location and no one from outside is allowed on the set, so no one would panic and call the police.

The second way is to shoot this on some real street. How would one do this depends on the country in which the movie is shot. Probably in most countries you need to provide some forms, pay the fee, agree on the date and so on. After that, the street is blocked by the police and bystanders are not allowed on the closed streets and can clearly see, that the accident happening is guarded by the police and surrounded by a lot of cameras and staff.

An example of such a scene can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxld3mZSbX8). You can see, that all the people present there is the staff of production.